# How to get the measure at specific day in that week using MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2008

I am new to MDX,
I have a requirement, which is using the measure on that Saturday as the default of that week, I have a time dimension [CALENDAR], 
but there are multiple hierachies, different hierachies have different week start, that means in [CALENDAR].[h1].[DATE], the week start may be Thursday(weekday in nature calendar), in the other may be Sunday(in nature calendar), 
so I have to using [CALENDAR].[DATE], which is nature calendar, I can get the corresponding Saturday,

```
   with member measures.[Weekday]
   as datepart('w',[CALENDAR].[Fiscal].currentmember)
   member measures.[SatDay]
   as dateadd('d'
   ,7-datepart('w',[CALENDAR].[Fiscal].currentmember.MemberValue)
   ,[CALENDAR].[Fiscal].currentmember.MemberValue)

   select 
   {
   [Measures].[Plan Count]
   ,measures.[Weekday]
   ,measures.[SatDay]
   }    on 0,
  [CALENDAR].[Fiscal].[Date]   on 1
  from [MyCube]
```

but how can I the measure on that day?

Answer (score 0):

Try a sub-select using your date hierarchy containing week (Year-Week-Date).

```
with     member [Measures].[WeekDate] as 
        dateadd('d' ,7 - datepart('w',[Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].currentmember.MemberValue)
                                   ,[Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].currentmember.MemberValue)

select {[Measures].[WeekDate], [Measures].[Plan Count]} on 0,
        [Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].Children on 1
from (
    select ([Dim Date].[Year -  Week -  Date].[Week]) on 0
    from [cube]
    where (
        //filters if necessary
    )
)
```